# How to execute another php script from shell_exec

Tags: php, shell-exec

Am trying to execute script from `shell_exec` for the first time, i don't know where my problem is coming from the command or the path.
from few tutorial i followed i have printed out my `phpinfo()` as instructed, to see the `bin path`,  this is what i get in output `$_ENV['PATH']   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`. I tried using the below script but no luck can someone help me out please.

My files look like this

public_html/dir/exec_test.php as http://example.com/dir/exec_test.php

```
<?php 
 echo 'Script succeeded';
?>
```

public_html/dir/exec.php as http://example.com/dir/exec.php

```
<?php 
$postid = 3;
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin /home/uhs67388/public_html/dir/exec_test.php '".$postid."' 'alert' >> /home/uhs67388/public_html/alert_log/paging.log &");
//shell_exec("/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin ".__DIR__."/exec_test.php '".$postid."' 'alert' >> ".__DIR__."/../alert_log/paging.log &");
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at your http servers error log file, that is where you can read what your issue is: the path you specify in the execution call.

Comment: @arkascha i can't see anything in my log dir

Comment: You need the actual path from `phpinfo()`.  Probably `/usr/local/bin/php` or something.

Comment: I just printed error and i got this `Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in`

Comment: So your host doesn't allow it, probably the same for `exec()` and others.

Comment: @AbraCadaver please is there any other method i can use since they disabled it?

Comment: You haven't said why you want `shell_exec()`, so why not just `include('exec_test.php');`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver because it slowing down the page and users will have to wait till the scrip finish

Comment: If you can't `use shell_exec()` You can use `$content = file_get_contents($filename);` to read the file and `eval($content);` to execute it. But usage of eval is **totally discouraged**. I just mention it because you asked if there is another method. But compared to `include()` this is much slower, more insecure and takes up more memory.

Comment: I have not test it but there is an alternative notation to `shell_exec()` thats the 'backtick' notation. Test if it is also disabled (probably yes but give it a try). http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php